# C# NAudio WaveStream only playing part of the time

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

My program is supposed to play the .wav file that I have put in. What it does is when I run it it plays the wave file, then the next few times I run it it doesn't play anything, then it plays the wave file again and repeats this cycle. Basically it randomly, or so it seems, ether plays the file or doesn't. I am using NAudio WaveStream to play it...

```
private static DirectSoundOut output = null;
private static BlockAlignReductionStream stream = null;
private static WaveFile song;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);

    song = new WaveFile(filePath);

    Wave wave = new Wave(song);
    stream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(wave);

    output = new DirectSoundOut();
    output.Init(stream);
    output.Play();

    while (true)
    {

    }
}

static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (output != null)
    {
        output.Stop();
        output.Dispose();
        output = null;
    }
    if(stream != null)
    {
         stream.Dispose();
         stream = null;
    }
}
```

The Wave class...

```
class Wave : WaveStream
{
    public WaveFile waveFile;
    public int sampleRate;
    public int bitDepth;
    public int channels;
    public byte[] byteArray;
    public long sample = 0;

    public Wave(int inputSampleRate, int inputBitDepth, int inputChannels, byte[] inputByteArray)
    {
        sampleRate = inputSampleRate;
        bitDepth = inputBitDepth;
        channels = inputChannels;
        byteArray = (byte[])inputByteArray.Clone();
    }

    public Wave(WaveFile inputWaveFile)
    {
        waveFile = inputWaveFile;
        sampleRate = waveFile.sampleRate;
        bitDepth = waveFile.bitDepth;
        channels = waveFile.channels;
        byteArray = (byte[])waveFile.byteArray.Clone();
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return long.MaxValue; }
    }

    public override WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return new WaveFormat(sampleRate, bitDepth, channels); }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int numBytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = byteArray[sample + i];
        }

        sample += numBytes;

        return numBytes;
    }
}
```

WaveFile class...

```
class WaveFile
{
    public int chunkID;
    public int chunkSize;
    public int format;
    public int fmtID;
    public int fmtSize;
    public int fmtCode;
    public int channels;
    public int sampleRate;
    public int fmtAvgBPS;
    public int fmtBlockAlign;
    public int bitDepth;
    public int fmtExtraSize;
    public int dataSize;
    public byte[] byteArray;

    public WaveFile(String filePath)
    {
        Stream waveFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(waveFileStream);

        Console.Write("Chunk Id: " + reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.WriteLine("File is " + (chunkSize = reader.ReadInt32()) + " bytes long.");
        Console.Write("Format: " + reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write("SubChunk Id: " + reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.WriteLine("SubChunk is " + (fmtSize = reader.ReadInt32()) + " bytes long.");
        Console.WriteLine("Audio Format: " + (fmtCode = reader.ReadInt16()));
        Console.WriteLine("channels: " + (channels = reader.ReadInt16()));
        Console.WriteLine("SampleRate: " + (sampleRate = reader.ReadInt32()));
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes for each second: " + (fmtAvgBPS = reader.ReadInt32()));
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes for sample: " + (fmtBlockAlign = reader.ReadInt16()));
        Console.WriteLine("BitDeapth: " + (bitDepth = reader.ReadInt16()));
        Console.Write("SubChunk2 Id: " + reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.Write(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadChar());
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes for enitre audio data: " + (dataSize = reader.ReadInt32()));


        if (fmtSize == 18)
        {
            // Read any extra values
            fmtExtraSize = reader.ReadInt16();
            reader.ReadBytes(fmtExtraSize);
        }

        byteArray = reader.ReadBytes(dataSize);

        waveFileStream.Dispose();
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My question why does this code play audio only sometimes when I run it. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `buffer[i + offset] = ...`. Also `byteArray[sample + i]` sooner or later will throw exception. And show us code for `WaveFile` class.

Comment: why aren't you just using `WaveFileReader`?